# How to provide command line arguments to save a file to a particular location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I have been using sys.argv to provide parameters in the command line.

For example, I have a method:

```
def function(param1, param2):
    # Stuff goes here.

def main():
    ... sys.argv[1] ...
    ... sys.argv[2] ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Now when I run this code the command will be something like this:

```
python filename.py param1 param2
```

The param can be anything, from paths to filenames set as and when required.

My question is how to set a parameter in which you can set a destination to store a file, say a pickle file for example. I would like to know how to do something like this:

```
python filename.py param1 param2 param3
```

where param3 is basically the destination of the file to be saved. If there is something like sys where we can provide a destination for a file to be saved using param1 and param2.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can you please explain with examples?

Comment: what are param1, param2 and param3 and what do they do?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your just trying to setup a quick-and-dirty script, it's rarely good idea to use `sys.argv` directly to get script arguments. Instead, use a command line argument parser. There are plenty out there for Python that are robust and fairly easy to use.

Here's a simple example using the default argument parser that comes with Python; [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). The script expects a single argument - a file path.

```
import argparse

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('file_path', help='A file path')
    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    args = get_args()
    if args.file_path:
        with open(args.file_path) as file:
            file.write('Lorem ipsum dolor sit.')
```